# Not getting column of table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE login(
  name varchar(200),
  email varchar(200) primary key, 
  count int,
  depart varchar(200),
  type varchar(1),
  password varchar(40));

CREATE TABLE qsstudent(
 department varchar(200),
 qs int,
 email varchar(200),
 type varchar(1),
 qscorrect int,
 qsdone int,
 qswrong int ,
 FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES login(email));

CREATE TABLE qsteacher(
  email varchar(200),
  department varchar(200),
  qsentered int,
  type varchar(1),
  FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES login(email));
```

When I run the query below, it cannot find the `login.depart` column. I have tried doing this several times but it is not running. I don't think that there is an error in the foreign key

```
   SELECT qsteacher.qsentered 
   FROM login,qsteacher 
   WHERE login.depart=qsteacher.department 
   AND qsstudent.email=login.email;
```

but still the error persists.

Comment: yea, where is the login table in your query?

Comment: and qsstudent table too

Comment: qsteacher what kind of table is?

Comment: `password varchar(40)` that's already a bad start, which suggests you're not using `password_hash()` which requires a minimum of 60 length, or you didn't set it high enough.

Comment: I added the login tabe in my query and my quey looks something like this now,

Comment: Select qsteacher.qsentered from login,qsteacher where login.depart=qsteacher.department and qsstudent.email=login.email;

Comment: ........... seems you want to drop code in comments. Edit your question instead. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41382657/edit

Comment: but its still giving and error

Comment: *"but its still giving and error"* - being? add that in your question also

Comment: `count int,` that requires a length, as does all others using `int`. RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: Not exactly sure what results your looking for, but if you want login.depart you have to join to that table. And where is your qsteacher column or table if your querying for it?

Comment: @leok please can u tell me the join query

Comment: [*Read **this** again.......*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382657/not-getting-column-of-table#comment69967539_41382657) why that comment hasn't received up votes, I'll never know - *"but still the error persists"* - being what? again.

Comment: Can you please put up the qsteacher table code

Comment: @Fred-ii- but is it a must to add a length. I dont think so, as my table does not show any errors?

Comment: @leok, added as you said, sorry for the indentation part

Comment: @leok thanx for the edit. Did not know how to do it

Comment: @AbhayGoyal fair enough. However you stated *"but still the error persists"* - yet after you state: *"as my table does not show any errors"* - I'm confused. If you say the error persists, then there should have been errors "shown".

Comment: @AbhayGoyal [Read this comment again that I left from earlier...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41382657/not-getting-column-of-table#comment69967363_41382657). Why create a table that is only going to be unsafe, unless this is just to practice with and not intended to be used in a live site.

Comment: @Fred-ii- when i say the "problem persists" it does not mean that my table is wrong but what i actually mean is that the query is not giving the intended result

Comment: you've been given an answer below and a long time ago; did you not try that?

Comment: @i was not quite satisfied as some changes had to be made in the previous structure which i had made and i do not want to change my previous structure because it was made for a reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot find the login.depart column

This is the exact thing your query can't find:

```
SELECT qsteacher.qsentered 
FROM login,qsteacher
WHERE login.depart=qsteacher.department 
AND qsstudent.email=login.email; //<-- you didn't select qsstudent
```

If you want to use `qsstudent` on this query you need add it to the `FROM`

```
FROM login,qsteacher,qsstudent
```

I recommend to do something like this with INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT T3.qsentered 
FROM login as T1
INNER JOIN qsstudent as T2 on T2.email=T1.email
INNER JOIN qsteacher as T3 on T1.depart=T3.department
```

and If you want to select by specific user just add this `WHERE` to the end:

```
WHERE T1.email = 'user_email'
```

Comment: thanx  a lot. Found it very useful

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your primary key should be an id, not an email, for multiple reasons, like uniqueness and index. So I will add an id to all of your tables which should auto increment with every record. And Your foreign key should be an id as well so I will change that.

```
CREATE TABLE login(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  name varchar(200),
  email varchar(200), 
  count int,
  depart varchar(200),
  type varchar(1),
  password varchar(40));

CREATE TABLE qsstudent(
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
 department varchar(200),
 qs int,
 email varchar(200),
 type varchar(1),
 qscorrect int,
 qsdone int,
 qswrong int ,
 FOREIGN KEY (login_id) REFERENCES login(id));

CREATE TABLE qsteacher(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  email varchar(200),
  department varchar(200),
  qsentered int,
  type varchar(1),
  FOREIGN KEY (login_id) REFERENCES login(id));
```

Now for the query that you are trying to run from what I can tell:

```
SELECT q.qsentered FROM qsteacher q
JOIN login l ON l.id = q.login_id
JOIN qsstudent s ON s.login_id = l.id
WHERE s.department = q.department
```

Please comment exactly what it is you are trying to query so I can better answer your question. It is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Email should and can be unique, so I disagree with your assertion that primary keys should be auto-incrementing ID's all of the time. Same goes for user names. What you're suggesting is bad design.

Comment: The table presented in the question has no unique constraint on emails. If it did then yes, it is a viable option, altough seldom used @JayBlanchard

Comment: the reason i made the email or rather i should be saying username is that i wanted it to be unique and hence making it so would help me to hard code some part of analysis so that i can get a unique email or username as you may say.

Comment: @AbhayGoyal Does the above solution work for you, can you give me more information on what you are trying to query

Comment: @leok actually what basically i want to do here is that i want to enter such values in the email column that they are not null and unique at the same time. As i am saving the details of some users in this table.